# Whats the correct way to pass a function to cProfile in python?

Tags: python, benchmarking, cprofile

I'm trying to benchmark my code using the `cProfile` and `pstats` libraries. This is the code I've got so far:

```
profile = cProfile.Profile()
profile.runcall(gillespie_tau_leaping(propensity_calc, popul_num, LHS, stoch_rate, popul_num_all, tao_all, rxn_vector, delta_t, tao, epsi))
ps = pstats.Stats(profile)
ps.print_stats()
```

I'm trying to benchmark the `gillespie_tau_leaping` function whose inputs are all arrays except for `propensity_calc` which is an function, `epsi` and `delta_t` which are constants.

Only at the moment I'm getting the following error:

```
File "c:/Users/Mike/visual studio code project/MSc dissertation code/tau_leaping_variant_ssa.py", line 190, in <module>
profile.runcall(gillespie_tau_leaping(propensity_calc, popul_num, LHS, stoch_rate, popul_num_all, tao_all, rxn_vector, delta_t, tao, epsi))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

On the line `profile.runcall(gillespie_tau_leaping(propensity_calc, popul_num, LHS, stoch_rate, popul_num_all, tao_all, rxn_vector, delta_t, tao, epsi))`

I've had a similar problem before where I wasn't actually passing the function as an argument instead I was calling the function and passing the results (which was a tuple) to the built-in function, which according to the documentation requires a function to be passed to it.

Is it the same problem here, and if so how do I fix it (I never figured it out last time)

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

For this, and most functions like it, you pass the function itself, uncalled, then the arguments to the function, as arguments to `runcall`; [it's documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#profile.Profile.runcall) to take a `func`, followed by varargs and kwargs (`*args` and `**kwargs`). All you change is removing the call parens for the function, and putting a comma after the function to separate it from its arguments:

```
profile.runcall(gillespie_tau_leaping, propensity_calc, popul_num, LHS, stoch_rate, popul_num_all, tao_all, rxn_vector, delta_t, tao, epsi)
```

Comment: Can `runcall()` output to a file? The documentation says: "Instead of printing the output at the end of the profile run, you can save the results to a file by specifying a filename to the `run()` function". is there something similar for `runcall()`? The documentation barely mentions it and the source code for neither function seems to indicate that a filepath is accepted.

Comment: @KurtWheeler: Yes, `profile.run` (the module level function) is a wrapper around various methods of a `profile.Profile` object. AFAICT, `profile.run`, when passed a `filename` argument, is roughly equivalent to creating a `profile.Profile`, calling `.run` on it (which does *not* take a `filename` argument), then calling `.dump_stats(filename)` on it. You can do the same thing manually, replacing the `.run` call with a `.runcall` call.